# Undefined property: CI_Loader::$pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

im working on a pagination function for my site i am using **Codeigniter** and i keep getting an error message that i cant fix it makes my head hurt :D can some one take a look at my code and tell me where i have went wrong. im only a bigginer.

the error is `Undefined property: CI_Loader::$pagination` and also `Fatal error: Call to a member function create_links() on a non-object in C:\....` tnx for ur help

```
view.php

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <meta name=description content="">
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <link rel=stylesheet href="css/style2.css">
        <link rel=author href="humans.txt">

     </head>
   <body>


            <h1>Answer</h1>
            <?php if (isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>

      <div = 'container'>
         <!--pagination -->
         <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>

          <ul>
              <h1><?php  echo  $row->question; ?></h1>
             <li><?php  echo  $row->answer1; ?></li>
               <li><?php  echo  $row->answer2; ?></li>
               <li><?php  echo  $row->answer3; ?></li>
               <li><?php  echo  $row->answer4; ?></li>
               <li><?php  echo  $row->answer5; ?></li>
               <li><?php  echo  $row->answer6; ?></li>
          <ul>
       </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          <?php else : ?>
          <h2>no records were returned</h2>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

class Survay extends CI_Controller{

    function index()
    {
        $data = array(
            'question' => $this->input->post('question'),
            'answer1' => $this->input->post('answer1'),
            'answer2' => $this->input->post('answer2'),
            'answer3' => $this->input->post('answer3'),
            'answer4' => $this->input->post('answer4'),
            'answer5' => $this->input->post('answer5'),
            'answer6' => $this->input->post('answer6'),
        );


        if($query = $this->membership_model->get_records())
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }

        $this->load->view('survay_view', $data);

    }



    function page()
    {
        //pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/admin/index.php/survay';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('save_survay')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['num_links'] =20;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->db-get('save_survay', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->load->view('survay_view', $data);
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller, before the `$this->load->view...` row you should do this:

```
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

and in the view, replace `echo $this->pagination->create_links()` with

```
echo $pagination;
```

**Update**

*Source: See Jeemusu's comment below*

I missed the part, that you're using the same view in two controller methods, and you are not adding pagination in one view.

so, instead of just adding `echo $pagination;` you should add this:

```
// check if $pagination variable is existing
if (isset($pagination))
{
    echo $pagination;
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to wrap that in an `if(isset($pagination)) {}` as the same view `survay_view` is being used for both `index()` and `page()` methods, but pagination data is only being set in the page() method.

Comment: tnx for ur help but can u expand more on ur comment im a noob on php :) tnx

Comment: the errors were fixed but the pagination is not showing up on the page do u have any more suggestions ?

Comment: @EdvinasLiutvaitis check your pagination config, especially this:`$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('save_survay')->num_rows();`. Does that return a nonzero value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to autoload the pagination library... just loading it in the function will not do.