# pagination not working unsolved error

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

hi everyone i am trying to build a pagination function in a web project i fallowed the user guide on codeigniter and a tutorial on net tuts here is the link `http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/`
but i keep getting these tow errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$pagination

Filename: views/result_view.php

Line Number: 41
```

and

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function create_links() on a non-object in C
```

cant figure these errors out where are they coming from and how can i fix them can some one help me here is my cmv :

**controller**

```
<?php

class Result_controller extends CI_Controller{

    function getall(){

        $this->load->model('result_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->result_model->result_getall();
       // print_r($data['query']); die();
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);

        }

        function pagination()
        {

            $this->load->library('pagination');

            $config['base_url'] = 'result_controller/pagination';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('data')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['num_links'] = 3;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->db->get('data', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);




        }
```

**view**

```
 <table border="1">


  <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Second Name</th>
     <th>Phone</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Answer</th>
     <th>Comment</th>
 </tr>
  <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?> 
 <tr>

     <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->second_name; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->phone; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $row->answerA;?>
      <?php echo $row->answerB;?>
      <?php echo $row->answerC;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->comment;?><br></td>

 </tr>

      <?php endforeach; ?>

     </table>  
     <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

**model**

```
<?php

class Result_model extends CI_Model{

    function result_getall(){

         return $this->db->select('*')
                         ->from('tblanswers, credentials')
                         ->get()
                         ->result_object();

    }



}



?>
```

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869637/undefined-property-ci-loaderpagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your view

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

And paste this one

```
<?php echo $pagination ?>
```

**EDIT**

Instead of having a pagination function put the pagination code inside your getall() function like this:

```
class Result_controller extends CI_Controller{

    function getall(){

        $this->load->model('result_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->result_model->result_getall();
        // print_r($data['query']); die();


        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'result_controller/getall';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('data')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['num_links'] = 3;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['records'] = $this->db->get('data', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);

        }
```

}

Comment: it removed the second error but i am still keep getting  Undefined variable: pagination error any suggestons why ? tnx for ur help bdv.

Comment: I've updated my code, copy the code of the controller I posted And replace the code of the controller you posted with the one I gave you

Comment: there are no error but the pagination is not displaying on the web page any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you edited your view file? and put the <?php echo $pagination ?> code?